# overwrite an excel file with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i want to overwrite an excel file with sailsJs, but really i don't know how to do it.I tried node-xlsx,exceljs but none works for me.I don't want to create a new file but modify an existing file. is there anyone who have an idea of how to do it? Thanks in advance.
this is my code:

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");
excel:function(req,res){
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.writeFile("test.xls")
.then(function() {
var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");
var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("My Sheet");
worksheet.columns = [
        { header: "Id", key: "id", width: 10 },
        { header: "Name", key: "name", width: 32 },
        { header: "D.O.B.", key: "DOB", width: 10 }
    ];

worksheet.addRow({id: 1, name: "John Doe", dob: new Date(1970,1,1)});
worksheet.addRow({id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", dob: new Date(1965,1,7)});
});

}
```

This created a file named "test.xls" but this file is empty and doesn't contain any of the informations i pass in like parameters of the row.

Comment: Share whatever you have tried so experts can help you in better way !

Comment: Hi, i am trying to do the same thing and want to append to a existing file, but using new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter seems to overwrite the file. Any pointers as to what i could be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xlsx.writeFile only works for when writing to CSV files. You would need to open a stream to edit an XLS file. More information is available in the [documentation](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#writing-xlsx).

Here is an example (not tested) of what you would need to do to write to an existing excel file.

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");

excel:function(req,res){
  // This creates a file and is not needed.
  // You will need to open a stream instead
  // var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  // workbook.xlsx.writeFile("test.xls");

  // You can find an example of the code here:
  // https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#writing-xlsx
  var options = {
    filename: "./test.xls", // existing filepath
    useStyles: true, // Default
    useSharedStrings: true // Default
  };

  var workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);
  var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");
  var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("My Sheet");

  worksheet.columns = [
      { header:"Id", key:"id", width:10 },
      { header:"Name", key:"name", width:32 },
      { header:"D.O.B.", key:"DOB", width:10 }
  ];

  worksheet.addRow({id: 1, name: "John Doe", dob: new Date(1970,1,1)});
  worksheet.addRow({id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", dob: new Date(1965,1,7)});
  worksheet.commit(); // Need to commit the changes to the worksheet

  workbook.commit(); // Finish the workbook
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.This helps me to write in the file. But i still have a problem. In fact it seems that this code erase what i have in the sheet "My Sheet" of the existing file and that it creates a new sheet "My sheet" to write the information. I want to add my information to the existing file. I tried to remove the instruction ' var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet"); ' so that the information will be written in the sheet of the existing file, but that generates error. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry for digging up old stuff but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xlsx' of undefined` at the `var workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);` line. I am however, loading in the lib like this `import * as Excel from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js";` because I keep getting `cannot find module "."` errors.